# Download source files from Firebase

Tags: git, firebase, version-control, file-recovery

I have a React.js project I made a while ago where, for the last month of development, I didn't push any changes to Git and the laptop that I used was wiped clean. The website is hosted on Google Firebase. Is there any way to download the source files from Firebase to recover my work?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't push your changes and the laptop was wiped, there is no way for you to recover those changes. Those changes were only applied to your local repository (your laptop).